# How to write features in file geodatabases (FileGDB) with GDAL and Python?

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, file-geodatabase-api

I am trying to copy features from a spatiallite database to a filegeodatabase. The target FileGDB already exists with the required feature classes.
I am using the FileGDB-API 1.4 on Ubuntu and Python 2.7.6.

```
from osgeo import ogr
#define db paths
psimgdb='/home/ubuntu/Simulation.gdb'
psrcdb='/home/tmp/2011.db'

#open connections
indriver=ogr.GetDriverByName('SQLite')
srcdb = indriver.Open(psrcdb,0)
outdriver=ogr.GetDriverByName('FileGDB')
simgdb = outdriver.Open(psimgdb,0)

#get input and output layers
inp_main=src.GetLayer('conduit')
out_main=gdb.GetLayer('msm_link')

#cycle through the features in the input layer
for feature in inp_main:
    outfeature = ogr.Feature(out_main.GetLayerDefn())
    outfeature.SetGeometry(feature.GetGeometryRef())
    outfeature.SetField('ID',feature.GetField('id'))
    out_main.CreateFeature(outfeature)
    outfeature.Destroy()

#close connection
simgdb=None
srcdb=None
```

The script runs fine, when I debug the code I can see that the attributes are created correctly on the target features, but no data is written to the file geodatabase "simgdb". Am I missing something here?
I have also tried del out_main, simgdb.Destroy(), del simgdb and

```
out_main.StartTransaction()
out_main.CreateFeature(outfeature)
out_main.CommitTransaction()
```

as shown for PostGIS databases in the Python GDAL/OGR cookbook, without success.

--UPDATE--
I actually realized that the CreateFeature function returns with error code 6. Not sure what this means...

Comment: normally to write features, i have to open the output file with editable=True, or in this case simgdb = outdriver.Open(psimgdb,1) #instead of 0